# jquery select this parent from inside image

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following code, i'm trying to make a loader appear then the image fade in once it is loaded. I want to make the function reusable so i can just add an image to a div with the loader id and it will work.

I cant figure out how to select the parent loader div from inside the image. the commented line works fine but, i think that will select all divs. i just want to select the parent loader div. can anyone help, thanks.

```
<div id="loader" class="loading">
  <img src="http://www.inhousedesign.co.nz/images10/caravan_01.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
</div>  

$("#loader").each(function(){
    var source = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
    var img = new Image();

    $(img).load(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      //$("#loader").removeClass('loading').append(this);
      $(this).parents("div:first").removeClass('loading').append(this);
      $(this).fadeIn(800);
    }).attr('src', source);    
  });
```

Comment: the commented line will only select the div with id=loader.  Since you shouldn't have multiple divs with the same id it should only select one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method?

```
 $(this).parent().removeClass('loading').append(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, is the make the background of the div have loading.gif...

```
#div {
   background:url(loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

And then have the img fade in when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

As derek says. the #loader selects div with id loader and there should only be one

If you are trying to make generic for many give the div a class and use parent selector

e.g

```
$(this).parent().removeClass('loader')
```